# Nested For-Each flattens?

Tags: powershell

There's an array of objects, where each has a collection of objects, where each has a string property. When I do a nested iteration:

```
$TheArray | %{$_.TheCollection | %{$_.TheProperty}}
```

it seems like I end up not with an array of string arrays, but with a 1D array of strings. Is that by design? That **is** the desired behavior in the first place, but utterly unexpected.

Comment: `@($TheArray | %{,@($_.TheCollection | %{$_.TheProperty})})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- PowerShell **by default *enumerates* (unrolls) collections**<sup>[1]</sup> when outputting them to the pipeline: that is, instead of outputting the collection *itself*, its *elements* are output, *one by one*.
- PowerShell **collects all output objects from a pipeline in a flat array** (of type `[object[]]`, i.e. an array whose elements can be of any type ([`System.Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Object))), if *two or more* objects are output (a *single* object is collected *as itself*).

Therefore, even outputting *multiple* arrays creates a *single*, flat output array by default, which is the *concatenation* of these arrays.

A simpler example:

```bash
# Output 2 2-element arrays.
PS> 1..2 | % { @(1, 2) } | Measure-Object | % Count
4  # i.e., @(1, 2, 1, 2).Count
```

---

In order to produce *nested* arrays, you must **suppress enumeration**, which can be achieved in two ways:

- Simplest option: **Wrap the output array in an *auxiliary, transient single-element array*** so that when PowerShell enumerates the aux. array its one and only element - the original array - is output *as a whole*, as a *single object*. This can be achieved with the **unary form of `,`** the [array-constructor ("comma") operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#comma-operator-):

```bash
# Use unary , to wrap the RHS in a transient single-element array,
# which ensures that @(1, 2) is output *as a whole*.
PS> 1..2 | % { , @(1, 2) } | Measure-Object | % Count
2  # i.e., @(@(1, 2), @(1, 2)).Count
```

- Alternative, using **`Write-Output -NoEnumerate`** (PSv4+; this is slower, but conceptually more explicit):

```bash
PS> 1..2 | % { Write-Output -NoEnumerate @(1, 2) } | Measure-Object | % Count
2  # i.e., @(@(1, 2), @(1, 2)).Count
```

Note:

- While use of `@(...)` is not strictly necessary to create array *literals* (as used above) - for literals, separating elements with `,` is sufficient<sup>[2]</sup> - you still need `@(...)` to ensure that output from enclosed expressions or commands is treated as an array, in case only a *single* object happens to be output.

---

<sup>[1] Specifically, types that implement the [`System.Collections.IEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.IEnumerable) interface or its [generic counterpart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable-1) are enumerated, but there are a few exceptions, notably strings and dictionaries. See the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65530467/45375) for details.</sup>

<sup>[2] E.g., `1, 2` creates a two-element array. In the case of *nesting* such an array via *unary* `,`, you *do* need an enclosure, however, to clarify *precedence*, for which the general-purpose `(...)` ([grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--)) would suffice: `, (1, 2)` - though you may prefer `, @(1, 2)` for conceptual clarity.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that output makes sense to me, at least on an intuitive level. I can't explain in accurate technical detail, but the only object written to the pipeline in your expression

```
$TheArray | %{$_.TheCollection | %{$_.TheProperty} }
```

is the inner-most

```
$_.TheProperty
```

Since this evaluates to a String, a number of Strings are accumulated in the pipeline and returned in an array.

Here's some sample code that mocks-up what you've described:

```
class HasProperty {
    [String] $TheProperty;
    HasProperty ([String] $prop){
        $this.TheProperty = $prop
    }
}

class SomeObject {
    [HasProperty[]] $TheCollection
    SomeObject ([HasProperty[]] $array) {
        $this.TheCollection = $array
    }
}

[SomeObject[]]$TheArray = @()

$TheArray = foreach ($i in (0..9)) {
    [HasProperty[]]$tempArray = foreach ($n in (0..3)) { [HasProperty]::new("Property$i-$n") }
    [SomeObject]::new($tempArray)
}
$TheArray | %{$_.TheCollection | %{$_.TheProperty} }
```

PowerShell's object-oriented pipeline makes it easy to extract values from some collection of objects. I've used it to get the group membership of a collection of users to determine how their memberships overlap, for instance.